# multiple joins on the same column with alias

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm trying to join multiple tables together. 2 of the tables need to be joined on the same column. However, I need to use the specified column alias as the values will only match after replacement of text. 
So I have;

```
table1:
| date_time | product_quote | category_id

table2: 
| product_id | category_id

table3: 
| date | product_id | sales

table4: 
| category_id | category_name
```

The value of 'product_quote' is a string that contains the product_id. I can get to this by using REPLACE.

Desired result:

```
| year | month | week | day | product_id | quotes | sales | category_name
```

I'm trying to use the following query, but it complains that 'product_id' is ambiguous.
When I do the third join on table2.product_id it executes the query but I get wrong sales numbers. 
Also not sure how to (re)use the date aliases (year, month, etc) in the join statement.

```
SELECT  
    date_part('year', table1.date_time) as "year", 
    date_part('month', table1.date_time) as "month", 
    date_part('week', table1.date_time) as "week", 
    date_part('day', table1.date_time) as "day",
    REPLACE(REPLACE(table1.product_quote,'/quotes/',''),'.pdf','') as "product_id", 
    count(table1.product_quote) as quotes,
    table3.sales,
    table4.category_name
from table1
left join table2 ON "product_id" = table2.product_id
left join table4 ON table2.category_id = table4.category_id
left join table3 ON "product_id" = table3.product_id AND 
                        date_part('year', table3.date) = date_part('year', table1.date_time) AND 
                        date_part('month', table3.date) = date_part('month', table1.date_time) AND 
                        date_part('day', table3.date) = date_part('day', table1.date_time)  
where date_part('year', table1.date_time) = '2020'
group by year, month, week, day, table2.product_id, table1.product_quote, table4.category_name, table3.sales
```

Is this something I should be doing as 1 query with 3 joins or would I need to be using subqueries? (and if so, how? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are assuming that you are joining based on the "product_id" projection  (or 'alias' as you call it) in the `SELECT` part. But that is not the case. In SQL, the `JOIN` always happens first, so the `JOIN` part does not 'know' about the `SELECT`-Part.

To solve your issue, you need to

- use the `REPLACE` expression twice in the `JOIN`
- always prefix product_id with the table

---

```
SELECT  
    date_part('year', table1.date_time) as "year", 
    date_part('month', table1.date_time) as "month", 
    date_part('week', table1.date_time) as "week", 
    date_part('day', table1.date_time) as "day",
    REPLACE(REPLACE(table1.product_quote,'/quotes/',''),'.pdf','') as "product_id", 
    count(table1.product_quote) as quotes,
    table3.sales,
    table4.category_name
from table1
left join table2 ON REPLACE(REPLACE(table1.product_quote,'/quotes/',''),'.pdf','') = table2.product_id
left join table4 ON table2.category_id = table4.category_id
left join table3 ON REPLACE(REPLACE(table1.product_quote,'/quotes/',''),'.pdf','') = table3.product_id AND 
                        date_part('year', table3.date) = date_part('year', table1.date_time) AND 
                        date_part('month', table3.date) = date_part('month', table1.date_time) AND 
                        date_part('day', table3.date) = date_part('day', table1.date_time)  
where date_part('year', table1.date_time) = '2020'
group by year, month, week, day, table2.product_id, table1.product_quote, table4.category_name, table3.sales
```

At least the above is the basic solution.
You could also use aliases, if you project `table1` before the `join` using a subselect:

```
SELECT  
    t1.year,
    t1.month,
    t1.week,
    t1.day,
    t1.product_id,
    t1.quotes,
    table3.sales,
    table4.category_name
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    date_part('year', table1.date_time) as "year", 
    date_part('month', table1.date_time) as "month", 
    date_part('week', table1.date_time) as "week", 
    date_part('day', table1.date_time) as "day",
    REPLACE(REPLACE(table1.product_quote,'/quotes/',''),'.pdf','') as "product_id", 
    count(table1.product_quote) as quotes,
    from table1
) as t1
left join table2 ON t1.product_id = table2.product_id
left join table4 ON table2.category_id = table4.category_id
left join table3 ON t1.product_id = table3.product_id AND 
                        date_part('year', table3.date) = t1.year AND 
                        date_part('month', table3.date) = t1.month AND
                        date_part('day', table3.date) = t1.day
where t1.year = '2020'
group by t1.year, t1.month, t1.week, t1.day, table2.product_id, t1.product_quote, table4.category_name, table3.sales
```

Comment: thank you! I didn't realise the joins are executed first (which should have been obvious ;)